# Simple Angular JS Module Not Working, But Master Angular Script Working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm learning Angular JS and I wrote a super simple snippet of code but it doesn't seem to be working properly. [Here is the Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/14Y8x2lFvbWWSLwcUeFf?p=preview), and the code looks like this. I know Angular is working because the expression in the double curly bracket is evaluated in the HTML ( {{3 * 14}} = 42 ). The problem is that the text in the span is supposed to change based on the value in the input, so if it's divisible by 2 it is Bold and so on. So it seems the problem is that it won't use my custom javascript module. Is there anyway to fix this?

```js
//script.js

var root = angular.module('root', []);

root.controller('index', ['$scope', function($scope){
        $scope.value = 1;
        $scope.isBold = function(){
            return $scope.value % 2 === 0;
        };
        $scope.isItalic = function(){
            return $scope.value % 3 === 0;
        };
        $scope.isUnderlined = function(){
            return $scope.value % 5 === 0;
        };
    }]);
```

```html
<!-- index.html -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="root">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-controller="index">
            <input type="text" ng-model="value"/>
            <span ng-class="{bold: isBold(), italic: isItalic(), underline: isUnderlined()}">Example Text</span>
            <span>{{3*14}}</span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems ok. Just add this styles to your html to get the visual effect:

```
<style>
  .bold {font-weight: bold;}
  .underline {text-decoration: underline;}
  .italic {font-style: italic;}
</style>
```

Thanks to @naren-murali for the [DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/cnbuVKYsuYAfGzGLorcp?p=preview).

Comment: Include this demo also please [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/cnbuVKYsuYAfGzGLorcp?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks. This works, here is the new demo. https://plnkr.co/edit/UzTuYhEbE0vQY1w8iUm9?p=preview